# Por que esta questão ganhou 3 upvotes?

Tags: debate, qualidade, pergunta-específica

Questão: [Como adicionar botão à página de edição de um produto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5866/como-adicionar-botao-a-pagina-de-edicao-de-um-produto)

Transcrição da pergunta:

> Como faço para adicionar um botão à barra "Descrição" no página de edição de produto? O botão deve ficar apenas na tab Descrição, onde tem a descrição do produto.

É uma política de início de site dar upvotes para qualquer pergunta de novos usuários, mesmo que mal formulada, para atrair usuários?

Comment: Discussões relacionadas: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/732

Comment: @bfavaretto não seria o caso de esperar a pergunta melhorar para dar os upvotes então? Não é nem possível responder a pergunta do jeito que está. Daqui a pouco temos 1k perguntas fechadas com score +4

Comment: Talvez para quem conheça o Magento faça sentido... Vai saber o que se passa na cabeça de quem votou!

Comment: Acredito ser exatamente o que o @bfavaretto disse... Talvez isso seja mais uma questão sobre o uso do Magento. Reafirmo o que falei [em outro post aqui no meta:] (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/732/politica-sobre-perguntas-de-nivel-rtfm/744#744) se não for capaz de responder rapidamente a uma pergunta dessas, é porque você também não sabe. Deixe a questão em paz.

Comment: @bfavaretto por favor responda a pergunta, então, já que parece ser a resposta certa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você me perguntasse se eu votaria para fechar a pergunta, eu diria que não, pois não conheço nada do Magento, nem o suficiente para dizer se a pergunta é pouco clara ou ampla demais. Quem conhece a ferramente pode julgar isso com mais propriedade.

Mas minha opinião sobre a qualidade da pergunta é que é uma pergunta ruim, pela forma e pelo conteúdo (ou falta dele). Não tenho a menor ideia do que levou as pessoas a votarem a favor dela. O único motivo válido que consigo enxergar é esse ser um problema extremamente comum para usuários do Magento.

Answer (score 7):

O problema apresentado na pergunta é relativamente comum, aparentemente existe uma certa dificuldade em adicionar botões "personalizados" a determinadas páginas administrativas, e todos os métodos que conheço envolvem uma quantidade razoável de código e manipulações da estrutura para que tudo fique a funcionar em condições.

Para quem percebe do assunto, a pergunta está clara o suficiente. **MAS** para o conceito de pergunta "clara e especifica" que utilizamos neste site, a mesma carece a adição de mais informação, indicação de código e/ou captura de tela para melhor ilustrar o pretendido.

Por saber o que trata a pergunta, não voto para fechar, mas também não posso votar a favor pois na sua forma atual a mesma está abaixo dos requisitos mínimos para ser considerada uma pergunta útil, clara e demonstradora de um esforço de pesquisa por parte de quem a colocou:

[image: Captura de Tela]

<sup>O que me parece é que ninguém lê a mensagem que aparece quando vamos clicar na seta.</sup>

## Resposta

> É uma política de início de site dar upvotes para qualquer pergunta de novos usuários, mesmo que mal formulada, para atrair usuários?

**Não**, não existe nenhuma política de *upvote* para novos utilizadores (isso seria caridade ou algo do género).

Answer (score 3):

Eu sou um dos que deu upvote. O rapaz acabou de chegar no site e foi malhado por motivos injustos - se eu fosse ele nunca mais voltava.

A pergunta era ruim? Eu acho que **não**. Ele estava com um problema bem específico, e fez a pergunta exatamente no ponto. A desatenção foi do pessoal que - por exemplo perguntando a linguagem de programação, talvez nem saiba que Magento é escrito em PHP, talvez nem saiba o que é Magento.

A pergunta poderia ser melhorada? Claro que **sim**, mas não muito. Ele poderia deixar mais explícito que era sobre Magento, podia incluir a tag "php", e podia incluir uma **imagem** (*screenshot*). Seria o suficiente. O texto está bom. Embora indiferente para a resposta, ele poderia contextualizar mais dizendo para que serviria o botão. O pessoal podia orientar nesse sentido. Mas criticaram a pergunta só apontando motivos errados.

Na minha opinião, [esta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5943/como-inverter-uma-string-em-javascript) é bem pior, mas está no *hit parade* do *site*, com 20 upvotes, gratificação de 100 pontos... Nem por isso dei *downvote* ou fiquei malhando o "Cabeção". Tá certo que as respostas e a discussão ficaram muito interessantes - mas a pergunta revela que [não houve esforço em pesquisar](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Como+inverter+uma+string+em+javascript%3F).

Isso tudo me faz lembrar uma vez que perguntei a diferença entre width, innerWidth e clientWidth no SO em inglês... recebi uma metralhada de downvotes, comentários me insultando, e num instante a pergunta foi fechada. :-)

Bom... voltando pro caso em questão, quem esteve presente ali na hora está mais capacitado a entender o **porquê**. Primeira interação do rapaz aqui (tinha **1** de reputação). Pergunta completamente contextualizada, objetiva, dentro do que o *site* pretende. Faltando apenas dar um ajuste.

Aí é atacado por desatentos que nem viram a tag.

Teve um usuário que postou uma resposta apontando um defeito que a pergunta não tinha. A resposta recebeu 2 downvotes. Eu e outro usuário comentamos negativamente sobre a "resposta". O usuário deletou a resposta.

Tudo isso que se passou já não pode mais ser visto - a ["resposta"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHQVr.png) foi deletada, outros comentários foram deletados (inclusive o meu que comentava a "resposta"), a reputação do rapaz não é mais apenas **1**...

Portanto, certamente não se trata de política do *site*, mas foi por um **senso comum de justiça** que eu, e possivelmente mais dois outros usuários que eu não sei quem são, deram *upvote* - para comunicar ao rapaz que perguntou: olha, a sua pergunta **está boa**.

Afinal, a pergunta é mesmo muito boa - "Como faço para adicionar um botão à barra "Descrição" no página de edição de produto?" - é milimetricamente exata, útil, simples, clara e objetiva. Ele não tem a obrigação de ficar explicando o que é Magento num *site* de programadores. Além do mais, quem não souber, basta dar um hover na tag, que aparece a explicação:

[image: explicação sobre Magento]

No Magento, você tem uma loja virtual potente funcionando OOTB, mas assim como Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress e outros, o Magento é também uma plataforma de desenvolvimento. Você tem tudo já funcionando, mas tudo pode ser customizado. O rapaz quer saber exatamente o que ele está perguntando: "onde é que eu tenho que mexer para customizar a tab Descrição na página de edição do produto"...

Em suma: três pessoas que conhecem Magento visualizaram a pergunta.

Comment: A tradução da descrição da tag precisa ser melhorada.

Comment: Dei uma tapa na tag wiki e respectivo fragmento.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que as críticas é devido tanto a pergunta como a descrição ficarem abstrata. Não dava pra identificar a situação ou contexto que o usuário se encontrava, você tem que adivinhar, mais a única coisa que salvou foi a tag "magento", pois assim daria pra entender da onde se tratava.
Para uma questão desse tipo na minha opinião, deve-se pedir ao usuário pelo menos uma reedição da descrição. que faça uma mais clara e objetiva, detalhando os aspectos do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que nós podemos adotar aqui uma posição bem mais amigável do que o SO em inglês proporciona.

Ao notar perguntas mal formuladas, ou com erros de português, principalmente percebendo que o usuário é novo no site (pela reputação), acho que o primeiro passo deveria ser alertá-lo, ou com o conhecimento devido até editar a pergunta para um melhor entendimento de todos.

Criticar apenas não acrescentará nada ao site e muito menos a quem fez a pergunta, que se sentirá desconfortável e pode não querer mais participar dessa comunidade, em que o conteúdo é todo feito pelos usuários.

O ideal é que tentemos salvar o máximo de perguntas possíveis, principalmente de usuários novos, que com o tempo com certeza passarão a formular perguntas com melhor qualidade. É claro que existem casos que realmente o downvote é necessário, mas temos que usar o bom senso nesses casos.

Nesse caso em específico creio que o motivo dos upvotes foram ou por conhecimento da questão, ou por solidariedade a um usuário novo que foi criticado.

Em alguns casos por mais que a pergunta demonstre que não houve pesquisa, caso as respostas acrescentem um conteúdo novo para o site e útil para os usuários não vejo por que não relevar.

Comment: Eu não achei os comentários nessa questão especialmente agressivos. As pessoas só pediram mais informações.

Comment: Eu concordo que devemos ser mais amigáveis que no SO, mas não dá para deixar tudo aberto. Por enquanto, não sei até quando, podemos monitorar as perguntas por um tempo antes de fechar (http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/537). Mas se após esse tempo o autor não melhorar/esclarecer perguntas que não são claras (há controvérsias se é o caso dessa específica), acho que ela deve ser fechada.

Comment: Concordo que um padrão de qualidade deve ser mantido. O que digo é que primeiramente vale tentar "educar" nossos novos usuários. Se não der certo ai sim tomar uma atitude.

Answer (score 0):

Usuário "novatos" do SO - eu incluso - de certa forma vêem isso como uma gentileza e encorajamento à participação na questão. Se é correto ou não, não sei, mas evito dar upvote em questões muito amplas e que não desenhem um problema claro a ser resolvido.